# regmatch_t how can i get match only?

Tags: c

I don't think I understand how to return only the matched regular expression. I have a file that is a webpage. I'm trying to get all the links in the page. The regex works fine. But if I printf it out it will print out the line in which that match occurs. I only want to display the match only. I see you can do grouping so I tried that and am getting back an int value for my second printf call. According to the doc it is an offset. But offset to what? It doesn't seem to be accurate either because it would say 32 when character 32 on that line has nothing to do with the regex. I put in an exit just see the first match. Where am I going wrong?

```
  char line[1000];
  FILE *fp_original;
  fp_original = fopen (file_original_page, "r");

  regex_t re_links;
  regmatch_t group[2];
  regcomp (&re_links, "(href|src)=[\"|'][^\"']*[\"|']", REG_EXTENDED);

  while (fgets (line, sizeof line, fp_original) != NULL) {
    if (regexec (&re_links, line, 2, group, 0) == 0) {
      printf ("%s", line);
      printf ("%u\n", line[group[1].rm_so]);
      exit (1);
    }
  }

  fclose (fp_original);
```

Comment: When I run your program with a matching input, it prints `104`, which is not an offset but *is* the character found at the offset! (It's the ASCII code for the `h` of the `href` that is the first character of the matched string.) Did you confuse yourself by printing `line[group[i].rm_so]` instead of `group[i].rm_so`?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley You are correct that `line[group[1].rm_so]` does return the ascii code. But when I try to just use `group[1].rm_so` I get a warning: `warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘regoff_t’`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I could tell you how to fix that, but I'd like to fix something else first. A warning message that doesn't make sense to the user is a problem. The warning should contain all the information you need. And from my perspective, it does. I can't imagine *not* understanding it. You have an opportunity to help others who will be in your position in the future by explaining your thought process as you read the warning, right now, before the confusion leaves you and you become one of us...

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I understand I'm looking for an unsigned int with %u but I thought group[1].rm_so is an int because the value is an offset. I'm confused as to why it is saying it is of type regoff_t. According to http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regexp-Subexpressions.html `regoff_t is an alias for another signed integer type` . So I thought ok %u should be %d so it will be a signed integer...no luck. I actually solved the problem but it is separate from this discussion. I would like to learn why %d wouldn't work if regoff_t is an alias.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. The thing you didn't get was that "integer" and "int" aren't synonyms. "signed integer type" is a category that includes at least 5 types: `int`, `long`, `long long`, `short`, and `signed char`. On my x86-64 Linux box, `regoff_t` is `int`. But your machine uses something else. Now the solution... you can't make the printf format match your `regoff_t` argument (because it varies between implementations), so you have to do the opposite. Make the argument match the format, by casting it. `printf("%d\n", (int)group[1].rm_so)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**regmatch_t array**

regmatch_t is the *matcharray* that you pass to the *regex* call. If we pass 2 as the number of matches in *regex* we obtain in regmatch_t[0] the whole match and in regmatch_t[1] the submatch.

For instance:

```
size_t nmatch = 2;
regmatch_t pmatch[2];

rc = regex(&re_links, line, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
```

If this succeeded you can get the subexpression as follows:

```
pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &line[pmatch[1].rm_so],
pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - 1);
```

Here is an example on how to apply the above:

```
#include <regex.h>                                                              
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             

int main(void)                                                                  
{                                                                                
    regex_t preg;                                                              

    char *string = "I'm a link to somewhere";                               
    char *pattern = ".*\\(link\\).*";                                     

    size_t     nmatch = 2;                                                        
    regmatch_t pmatch[2];                                                         


    regcomp(&preg, pattern, 0);                                                   
    regexec(&preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, 0);                                    

    printf("a matched substring \"%.*s\" is found at position %d to %d.\n",       
     pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &string[pmatch[1].rm_so],  
     pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - 1);                                 

    regfree(&preg);                                                               

    return 0;                                                                     
}
```

Above code is certainly not save. It serves only as an example. If you exchange pmatch with your group it should work. Also don't forget to parenthesize the part of your regex you want to capture in your group --> `\\(.*\\)`

**Edit**

In order to avoid the warning by the compiler concerning the field precision, you can replace the whole printf part with this:

```
char *result;

result = (char*)malloc(pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so);
strncpy(result, &string[pmatch[1].rm_so], pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so);

printf("a matched substring \"%s\" is found at position %lld to %lld.\n",
       result, pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - 1);

// later on ...
free(result);
```

Comment: I get an error when I run what you have above. `test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:21: warning: field precision should have type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘regoff_t’
test.c:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘regoff_t’
test.c:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘regoff_t’`

Comment: well that's weird, because this runs perfectly on my site, even using differnt gcc versions...are you sure you've used exactly the same code?

Comment: @user983223 first of all, these are warnings, not errors, but i do agree with you, they are ugly and avoiding warning messages can be considered to be mandatory. see my edit on how to avoid these...

Answer (score 2):

the resulting match (your `group`) gives you a start index and an end index.  you need to print just the items between those two indeces.

`group[0]` will be the entire regex match.  the subsequent groups will be any captures you have in your regex.

```
for(int i = 0; i < re_links.re_nsub; ++i) {
    printf("match %d from index %d to %d: ", i, group[i].rm_so, group[i].rm_eo);

    for(int j = group[i].rm_so; j < group[i].rm_eo; ++j) {
        printf("%c", line[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

For a full example see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284582/how-can-i-easily-get-regex-selections-in-c/10284891#10284891).